# PostgreSQL: column does not exist when searched in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have this little SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT( distinct  (customerid)) AS cs,  prod_id 
FROM 
 (orderlines JOIN orders ON (orderlines.orderid=orders.orderid)) AS table_1  
WHERE table_1.cs= 1
GROUP BY table_1.prod_id
ORDER BY cs ASC
```

What this is supposed to do, is count the distinct **customerid**'s and return a table containing only the entries where there was only distinct **customerid**.

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column table_1.cs does not exist
LINE 6: WHERE table_1.cs= 1
          ^
*********Error********** 

ERROR: column table_1.cs does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 156
```

It claims that the column **cs** does not exist when I have clearly defined it here:

```
SELECT 
      COUNT( distinct  (customerid)) AS cs,  prod_id
```

Comment: You filter aggregate results with a having clause GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT( distinct  (customerid))=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference in a WHERE clause an alias defined in the Selection list. You can either use an HAVING clause or use a sub select ..

With a sub select you can arrange something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
  COUNT( distinct  (customerid)) AS cs,  prod_id 
FROM 
 (orderlines JOIN orders ON (orderlines.orderid=orders.orderid))
GROUP BY table_1.prod_id) AS table_1  
WHERE cs= 1
ORDER BY cs ASC
```